# Could not find method testPackageName() for arguments [com.android.volley.tests]

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I wanted to migrate from eclipse to studio. I followed a tutorial and tried to build the existing eclipse app in studio with gradle. I am facing the following issue while running this comment

```
 Rethinavels-Mac-mini:HomeStarProvider rethinavel$ ./gradlew clean
```

I am new to studio and gradle. How to fix this thing up? Any tutorials to learn gradle?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/rethinavel/Desktop/WorkSpace/HomeStarProvider/Volley/build.gradle' line: 9
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':Volley'.

  > Could not find method testPackageName() for arguments [com.android.volley.tests] on ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=main, minSdkVersion=null, targetSdkVersion=null, renderscriptTargetApi=null,

  renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=null, versionName=null, applicationId=null, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}.

Here is the Build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
                    repositories {
                        mavenCentral()
                    }
                    dependencies {
                        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+'
                    }
                }

    apply plugin: 'android'
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile project(':SliderLibrary')
        compile project(':Volley')
        compile project(':Google Play Services Library')
        compile project(':viewanimationLibrary')
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }


        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }

            // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
            androidTestCompile.setRoot('tests')

            // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
            // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
            // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
            // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
            // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
            // by a similar customization.
            debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
            release.setRoot('build-types/release')
        }

        productFlavors {
            flavor1 {
                applicationId "com.homestar.provider"
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like problem is in Volley build.gradle file. You use gradle version 1.0.0 and higher, but method `testPackageName` renamed to `testApplicationId` since this version. All changes in versions you can find on [Android Tools Project Site](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0)